# How to change react native push notifications status bar icon?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I am using `firebase` and `react-native-push-notification` to push notifications to my *Android* app and struggling to change the small notification icon with my own icon and none of the threads about this topic seems to help. I have the `ic_test.png` located in my `@mipmap` folder and none of these metadata declarations in my Android manifest work:

1.
`xml <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_test" />`

2.
`xml <meta-data   android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_test" />`

I am however able to change the color of the icon by adding metadata:

```xml
<meta-data  
  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
  android:resource="@android:color/white"
/>
```

**Situation:**

[image]

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Got it working for **local notifications** by not setting any icon metadata resource in the manifest. I just set the following metadata resource

```xml
<meta-data  
  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
  android:resource="@android:color/MY_COLOR"
/>
```

to change the background color of the icon.

Also, set the following key-value pair

```
PushNotification.localNotification({...parameters, smallIcon: 'ic_test'});
```

When triggering a local notification.

**EDIT:**

I am using [Firebase Cloud Messaging legacy HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) and setting the `icon` parameter to `"ic_test"` does not seem to do the trick also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it is showed like a white blank square because you are in the development mode, by building in production mode you can see the like exactly like your app icon.

How ever, if you wanna make your icon you sould follow [`material principles`](https://material.io/design/iconography). then generate all sizes by using [this link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit) and put the icon name `ic_notification`.

Then put all sizes `ic_notification` in the following address:

```sh
android/app/main/res/mipmap
```

And add the following line to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
```

Clean build folder, clean caches files and use `yarn start --reset-cache` and then `yarn android`.

**Hint**: if you are using emulator, aware of using `Cold Boot` instead of `Quick Boot` in your Emulator advance option.

Comment: Cleaning build folder and cache + Cold Boot really did it, thanks m8!